I used sea-orm and solana-sdk in my project,dependency conflict
error: failed to select a version for `zeroize`.
    ... required by package `curve25519-dalek v3.2.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `curve25519-dalek = "^3.2.1"` of package `solana-program v1.18.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-program = "=1.18.0"` of package `solana-sdk v1.18.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-sdk = "=1.18.0"` of package `solana-clap-utils v1.18.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-clap-utils = "^1.18"` of package `sol_utils v0.1.0 (/Users/solana/solana-learn/sol_utils)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `sol_utils` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `solana-learn v0.1.0 (/Users/solana/solana-learn)`
versions that meet the requirements `>=1, <1.4` are: 1.3.0, 1.2.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `zeroize v1.5.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `zeroize = "^1.5"` of package `rsa v0.9.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `rsa = "^0.9"` of package `sqlx-mysql v0.7.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sqlx-mysql = "=0.7.0"` of package `sqlx v0.7.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sqlx = "^0.7"` of package `sea-orm v0.12.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sea-orm = "^0.12.1"` of package `sea-orm-migration v0.12.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sea-orm-migration = "^0.12.0"` of package `migration v0.1.0 (/Users/solana/solana-learn/migration)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `migration` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `api v0.1.0 (/Users/solana/solana-learn/api)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `api` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `solana-learn v0.1.0 (/Users/solana/solana-learn)`

failed to select a version for `zeroize` which could resolve this conflict

